# How to Resolve 'Computer' is ambiguous between declarations in Modules 'GlbSoft.SWB.SS.My.MyProject' and 'GlbSoft.SWB.SS.My.MyProject'

Tags: vb.net, reference, declaration, ambiguous

I am trying to access the current NUM LOCK setting on a computer running VBA/VB.NET:
- Windows 7
- Visual Studio 2010
- Microsoft (Office) Excel 2010

Here is the code:

```
Public Const _GlobalDefinitions As String = "GlobalDefinitions"
Public Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)
Public Const VK_NUMLOCK As Integer = &H90
Public Const KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY As Integer = &H1
Public Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP As Integer = &H2
Public InitialNumLockState As Boolean

Public Sub CheckNumLockState(Optional mWriteback As SSWriteback = Nothing)
    Try
        If InitialNumLockState Then
            If Not My.Computer.Keyboard.NumLock Then
                keybd_event(VK_NUMLOCK, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or 0, 0)
                keybd_event(VK_NUMLOCK, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        If Not mWriteback Is Nothing Then
            AddToErrorLog(mWriteback, _GlobalDefinitions & ":" & System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.Name.ToString & "> " & ex.Message & ", " & ex.StackTrace, TraceEventType.Error)
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

The InitialNumLockState variable is set earlier in the process as follows:

```
    InitialNumLockState = My.Computer.Keyboard.NumLock
```

The initial reference to **My.Computer.KeyBoard.NumLock** works fine (and I can query it within a Watch window in runtime) and initializes the InitialNumLockState variable, e.g., True if the NUM LOCK key is ON.

In the second reference to **My.Computer.KeyBoard.NumLock**, however, I am getting the following error:

**'Computer' is ambiguous between declarations in Modules 'GlbSoft.SWB.SS.My.MyProject' and 'GlbSoft.SWB.SS.My.MyProject'.**

Note that the error message says the reference is ambiguous because it is present in **two modules with the same name**.  Of course, this is not possible.  There is only one project/namespace involved (GSI_SWB_SS/GlbSoft.SWB.SS).

Does anyone have any ideas or insight concerning this error and what can be looked at in order to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem at this moment in my application.
I think VS creates instance of `Computer` in each `My` of each `.dll`.
I bypassed the problem.

In my application, I have an infrastructure layer where I have added

```
Namespace Infrastructure.MYLOCAL
  <HideModuleName> _
  Public Module MYLOCAL
    Public MYComputer = My.Computer
  End Module
End Namespace
```

and as my whole application uses the infrastructure layer, it works.
I use `MYComputer` instead of `my.Computer`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible and this is exactly the error that appears.
Remember that in terms of the compiler what matters is not the name of the file, but the declaration made within it.
Look for duplicate declarations.

In my case someone made a backup copy of the file leaving it in the same folder and just renaming the file name to the backup date. Just find and change the file extension from .vb to something like .OLD